# Update the score of Pinned Documents in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to show some documents always on top of search results and for that, I have used pinned query to pin some documents and the pinned documents will have a score value of 1.7014122E38.

But I have another requirement to modify this score of pinned documents which I'm unable to achieve at the query level.

Sample Documents

```
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "jack"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "ryan"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "mark"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "taylor"
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "name": "taylor"
    }
  ]
}
```

ES Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "pinned": {
            "ids": [
              "3"
            ],
            "organic": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "name": "taylor",
                        "fields": [
                          "name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to multiply the pinned document score weight with some value which I'm unable to achieve in ES.

Can someone please help me to solve this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `pinned` queries' scores are calculated [at query time](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a92a647b9f17d1bddf5c707490a19482c273eda3/x-pack/plugin/search-business-rules/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/searchbusinessrules/PinnedQueryBuilder.java#L188), there's no way of knowing what they're will end up being. It could be `1.7014122E38` but also `1.7014122402528844E38` etc.

What you *could* do is use a sort script and check whether the implicit score is unusually high (I chose `Integer.MAXV_VALUE` as the boundary) which'd *indicate* whether or not you're dealing with a pinned. If that's the case, you can override the pinned documents' scores however you like.

```json
POST your-index/_search?track_scores&filter_path=hits.hits._id,hits.hits._source,hits.hits.sort
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "pinned": {
            "ids": [ "3" ],
            "organic": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "taylor",
                      "fields": [
                        "name"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "order": "desc", 
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "source": "_score >= Integer.MAX_VALUE ? params.score_rewrite : _score",
          "params": {
            "score_rewrite": 42
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that it's necessary to set the [`track_scores` URI parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#_track_scores) because when sorting on a field, the scores are not computed by default.

That way, the resulting hits would look along the lines of:

```json
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "3",        <-- pinned ID
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "mark"
        },
        "sort" : [
          42.0              <-- overridden sort
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "4",
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "taylor"
        },
        "sort" : [
          0.875468730926    <-- default sort
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : "5",
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "taylor"
        },
        "sort" : [
          0.875468730926
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

P.S.: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is arbitrary and there's absolutely no guarantee that it'll catch all pinned docs. In other words, a bit of experimentation will be needed to choose a bulletproof boundary.

Comment: Great answer. Tenary operator is supported in Painless which I couldnt explicitly find in the documentation. Debugging issues with scripts can be a challenge as the true error messages are a lot further down in the logs than normal.

Comment: Thanks Luke. Script debugging is a pain in the ass but there are a few things you can do. Check out [the end of this chapter](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/script-fields-debugging-bae4929eeaad414986d26f0b58187d66) of my ebook.